# How to check if my application in edge-to-edge mode above api level 30?

Tags: android, kotlin, fullscreen, android-api-levels, windowinsets

I was trying to solve some fullscreen problems past few days, finally I discover:
`WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)`

so I create an extension function:

```
fun Activity.fullScreen(isLightStatusBar: Boolean? = null) {

    if (window == null) {
        return
    }

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

//    // light / dark status bar
//    if (isLightStatusBar != null) {
//        val windowInsetsController = WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, window.decorView)
//        windowInsetsController.isAppearanceLightStatusBars = isLightStatusBar
//
//    }
//
//    // status bar color
//    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
//        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
//    }
}
```

```
fun Activity.undoFullScreen(isLightStatusBar: Boolean? = null) {

    if (window == null) {
        return
    }

    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
    // status bar color options etc.
}
```

which was seems like really promising. **But I couldn't find out any way to check through android api if I'm in edge-to-edge AKA fullscreen mode**. And now it's just another kind of pain. I have a insetListener like following:

```
window.decorView.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { v, insets ->
    val isFullScreen = hasFlag(window.decorView.systemUiVisibility, View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) ||
            hasFlag(window.decorView.systemUiVisibility, View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
    val navigationBarInsetsVisibility = WindowInsetsCompat.toWindowInsetsCompat(insets).isVisible(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.navigationBars())


    Log.d("EDDY", "window.attributes.flags=${window.attributes.flags} - window.decorView.systemUiVisibility=${window.decorView.systemUiVisibility}")

//            if (isFullScreen.not()) {
//                binding.content.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(insets)
//            }

    return@setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener insets
}
```

I'm changing `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` value while switching fragments. And according to this listener `navigationBarInsetsVisibility` is always true, which is make sense but also useless. `isFullScreen` is always false because there is no flag changes. How I'm supposed to know if my content is under the navbar or not?

The necessity of this information is: just because I want to add bottom padding to my content only if it is in fullscreen mode. But I can't detect it. Only solutin come to mind is setting `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN` along the `setDecorFitsSystemWindows`method but docs saying:

`Please note: using the View.setSystemUiVisibility(int) API in your app can conflict with this method. Please discontinue use of View.setSystemUiVisibility(int).`

So I'm confused and tired. How can I check if my app is in fullscreen mode?

PS: flags are being set below api 30. So I can check them but not 30 and above.

I tried to log flags but seems like no change. Also check navigation visibility but also doesnt change. And fun fact: navigation visibility showing confusing results on api 29. like, showing  visible while in full screen and not visible while not in fullscreen. I was expecting other way around.

**UPDATE**:
ok I find out that adding `setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener`to a `windows.decorview` is really a bad idea. I'm actually bypass'in all system's calls for "onApplyWindowInsets" But the question still remains, actually it's getting worse in this case:
if I can't get any event on undo-Fullscreen and if there isn't any variable to check for fullscreen mode. How am I supposed to control the custom paddings of my application?